# Visual Studio "0 of 4 errors"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to build my project and Visual Studio tells me I have erros in my project. The error window says it's listing "0 of 4 errors". Where can I find these errors?

This is a project that I've just created, so the only C# code I have is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class StationCreate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

which is essentially nothing. Then I have this file, the contents of which I copied from another I made:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StationCreate.aspx.cs" Inherits="StationCreate" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 761px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            font-size: large;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            width: 950px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div draggable="false" class="container">
    <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left" class="header">

                    <table class="auto-style1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

        <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text="Station Creator" style="font-weight: 700; font-size:48pt; font-family:'Segoe UI'; text-transform:uppercase;"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="StationIDLabel" runat="server" style="text-transform:uppercase;"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left">
    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="topTableCell">
        <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Black">Select a JOB</asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="topTableCell">
                    <span class="auto-style3">&nbsp;<br />
                    </span>
                    <asp:Button ID="GenerateButton" runat="server" Text="Generate" OnClick="GenerateButton_Click" Enabled="False" CssClass="button" Font-Size="XX-Large" ForeColor="Gray" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="DashboardButton" runat="server" CssClass="button" Font-Size="XX-Large" ForeColor="White" OnClick="DashboardButton_Click" Text="Dashboard" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />

        <div class="gridViewContainer">
            </div>
        <asp:Label ID="TestLabel" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you got multiple projects in your solution? Click on the other projects, you'll probably see them appear. "X out of Y errors" means "X errors in the current project out of Y errors in total".

Comment: There's only one project in my solution. I had opened another styles.css file from another location, but didn't save it or anything and I made a new styles.css

Comment: It might just be a matter of cleaning your solution. Select your solution and go to `Build` -> `Clean Solution` and try building it again. Restarting VS might also help.

Comment: It turns out I had a filter on the error list. I didn't notice it was on. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Many thanks, @JeroenVannevel from 2015!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It turns out that I just had a filter set on the error list. A silly mistake, but lesson learned!

EDIT:

The filter option on the error list can be found by clicking this button:

[image: fiter]

Here, it is not selected. If it is selected, you can choose to filter error messages/warnings based on which project the errors are within. By deselecting it (as in the image above), you will have no filter and you should see all errors.

Comment: Could you include a few details on how to check for a filter and how to remove it. It would actually turn this in to a pretty good question and answer.

Comment: Edited! See changes above.